# Customizing default login failure message SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

On the default FBA Login Page, when a user enters wrong username/password an error message gets displayed:

> "The server could not sign you in. Make sure your Username and
>   Password are correct, and then try again.".

I want to change this error message dynamically according to requirement.

Such as

> 'Invalid Username or Password', 'Your account has been locked'

Answer (score 0):

FBA failure message is coming from `Failure Test="<%$Resources:wss,login_pageFailureText%>"` , you can change the text to `FailureText="Invalid Username and Password , Your account has been locked"`

[Change Error Message on FBA Login page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113638/change-error-message-on-fba-login-page)

Or you can create your own [custom login page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pranab/2010/07/26/how-to-create-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010-form-based-authentication-fba/)  .

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Actually I need display message on condition based for example

if(Loginfail)
{
 lblmessage.text="Your login or password not valid"
}
else if(yourMaxLoginAttempts>5)
{
 lblmessage.text="your account has been locked"
}
else if(yourUserIdnotexixt)
{
 lblmessage.text="You are not Authorised user. Please register first."
}
else
{
 redirect to home page.
}
So please suggest the way.